# find pattern in between numbers and sum them?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

my file:

```
chr2    10145622        10170989        11
chr7    15682126        15682183        28
chr18   48064121        48064222        10,7
chr23   20637149        20637247        824,86
chr25   2063714         2072977         824,80,62,2
chr16   48064100        48064272        10,9
```

desired output:

```
chr2    10145622        10170989        11
chr7    15682126        15682183        28
chr18   48064121        48064222        17
chr23   20637149        20637247        910
chr25   2063714 2072977 968
chr16   48064100        48064272        19
```

i tried:

```
cat test.bed | sed 's/\,/\t/g' | awk '{OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3,$4+NF}'
```

but its also sum blank columns which is not correct. Indeed its true, as i have replaced "," into tab.

work well if we know up to the last columns

```
cat test.bed | sed 's/\,/\t/g' | awk '{OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3,$4+$5+$6+$7}'
```

However, I used `NF` meaning column 4 from to last column, suppose we don't know in file, how many pattern and their numbers we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the last field and sum its parts:

```
$ awk '{n=split($NF, a, ","); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) s+=a[i]; $NF=s; s=0}1' file
chr2 10145622 10170989 11
chr7 15682126 15682183 28
chr18 48064121 48064222 17
chr23 20637149 20637247 910
chr25 2063714 2072977 968
chr16 48064100 48064272 19
```

To handle input/output field separators, you can say `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}`, for example.

#### Explanation

- `n=split($NF, a, ",")` split the last field based on the comma separator. This way, you have an array `a` containing as many values as parts were sliced. `split()` returns the amount of "pieces", so we store it.
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) s+=a[i]; $NF=s; s=0` loop through the list of items in `a` and sum them in the variable `s`. (Note: `for (i in a)` would also work for this case, when the order doesn't matter). Then, set the last field to this value and reset the counter.
- `1` as it evaluates to True, it performs the default `awk` action: print current line.

Comment: I suspect `OFS=\\t` is desirable.

Comment: its true :)
thanks man, i did.
awk '{OFS="\t";n=split($NF, a, ","); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) s+=a[i]; $NF=s; s=0}1'

Comment: @Rupesh Nice! Note however that saying `awk '{OFS="\t"; ...}` is setting the output field separator every single time it starts reading a line. As it is a value that you want to be constant, you'd better place it in the `BEGIN` block or as a parameter with `awk -v OFS="\t" '{...}'`.

Comment: Or `awk '{...}' OFS=\\t filename`.  This allows you to change the value for each file: `awk '{...}' OFS=a file1 OFS=b file2`.  For reasons unknown to me, this is the most useful form, yet is the least used.

Comment: Uhms, @WilliamPursell this is indeed quite useful

Comment: +1 Since the order of accessing the array elements doesn't matter you could just use the `in` operator: `split($NF, a, /,/); for (i in a) s+=a[i]`. I used regexp delimiters instead of string delimiters for the 3rg arg for split() since it IS a regexp so it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks! In fact I was commenting this in my explanation. (I always wonder if anybody reads them :D)

Comment: @fedorqui oh yeah, so you did. idk if anyone reads explanations either - I usually don't give them and leave it up to the reader to think about it, try to figure it out, and ask questions if necessary :-).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` has a `split` function, that splits a string based on a RE and puts the parts into an array variable, you can `split` the last field of each line on a comma, and then sum the elements of the array

```
NF==4{split($4,arr,','); $4 = 0; for(i in arr) $4+=arr[i];}
1
```

NB1 this works IF AND ONLY IF there are no spaces between the nubers in $4
NB2 the last `1` forces the printing of the current line